# Mysql update multiple table

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like this:

```
create table t1 (id varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', money decimal(20,4) NOT NULL default '0');

create table t2 (id varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', money decimal(20,4) NOT NULL default '0');

insert into t1 values('1',1);

insert into t2 values('1',2);
insert into t2 values('1',3);
```

and I want add all the t2's money of the same id to t1, so I use the following sql:

`update t1,t2 set t1.money = t1.money + t2.money where t1.id = t2.id`.

and I thought the money of id '1' in table t1 should be

> 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

but actually it's

> 1 + 2 = 3;

it seems it always adds the first line of t2.

```
mysql> select * from t1;

+----+--------+
| id | money  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | 3.0000 |
+----+--------+
```

how can I get the value of

> 1 + 2 + 3

by one sql.

Comment: There is a SO site specifically for database questions :) http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is most likely due to the fact that the query is executed for each of the lines of t2. I think that the value gets overridden.

Comment: You should try a inner query, I'll put in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.money = (SELECT SUM(t2.money) + t1.money FROM t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id)
```

Comment: But does not take into account existing values in t1.

Comment: sorry, fixed " existing values in t1"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a inner query:

```
update t1 set t1.money = (select sum(t1.money) from t1) + (select sum(t2.money) from t2 where t2.id=t1.id)
```

or something similar.

Comment: thanks for all the answer, it actually works, but if table t1 has more than one column should to add up, for example, t1 has column money1 and money2 and money3, so should I write three inner query ?